# Using strings to access custom methods dynamically

Tags: apache-flex, string, flex3, variables

I am creating a two-dimensional list that has consecutive numbers at the end of "day", for use as dataProvider for a DataGrid
i have been accessing them via the command
dg1.selectedItem.day1
dg1.selectedItem.day2
dg1.selectedItem.day3
etc...

is there any way to take the string ("day"+i) and convert it into a (what is it? variable name?)
so that i can do something along the lines of:

```
for(var i:Number=1; i<numFields; i++)
{
  dg1.selectedIndex = i-1;
  dg1.selectedItem.(mysteryFunction("day"+i)) = 42;
}
```

if there's a function that i could use for mysteryFunction, or what data type to use, any info would be very helpful

this is what i've been using (so tedious):

> ```
> <mx:XMLList id="sched">
>   <field>
>       <day1></day1>
>       <day2></day2>
>       <day3></day3>
>   </field>
>   <field>
>       <day1></day1>
>       <day2></day2>
>       <day3></day3>
>   </field>
>
>   ...
> </mx:XMLList>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The "mystery function" you are looking for is as simple as indexing with brackets:

```
for(var i:Number=1; i<numFields; i++)
{
    dg1.selectedIndex = i-1;
    dg1.selectedItem["day"+i] = 42;
}
```

And it is called, surprisingly, an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [`Array`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/Array.html) or if you are going to bind it (which I am kind of betting on) use [`ArrayCollection`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/collections/ArrayCollection.html) instead of naming these variables individually.

If the members are generated by some program, you better put all of these in one of the collection classes I mentioned above and then start the processing. It makes life easier in the long run.

[E4X](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=13_Working_with_XML_03.html) is the way to go when dealing with XML. The Mozilla guys have an arguably better [explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Processing_XML_with_E4X) of that technology. So, if your XML is stored in a variable as:

```
var tree:XML = <field>
    <day1></day1>
    <day2></day2>
    <day3></day3>
```

You can simply do:

```
tree.day1 = 42;
```

Why would you want this `mysteryFunction()`? A `dataProvider` object is just a collection of some Type. You **know** the type already, right? Read [this](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=about_dataproviders_2.html).

Anyway, there is no such mystery function. Note, however, string concatenation with a number converts the number to a string. Try

```
trace("str " + 42);
```